# Compare pre-post change intervention across studies

Tags: anova, meta-analysis, pre-post-comparison

I have got a question regarding the comparison of the effect size comparing a new (digital) intervention with previous data using a traditional intervention. In summary, we've designed a **new (digital - smartphone based) intervention** and a **suited (digital) placebo - intervention**. We conducted an online study **comparing the pre and post scores** of **randomly assigned** participants (103 participants completed intervention, 180 completed placebo).
We used a **mixed-model ANOVA** with the factors TIME (pre, post) and the factor GROUP (treatment, placebo) and could show a **significant interaction effect**.

So far, so good. Now we want to set our results in **context to classical experiments** previously done in our lab. We've got **similar data** for the classical treatment vs. its placebo-procedure **of 4 separate studies** (20 vs. 20, 26 vs. 26, 20 vs. 20, 50 vs. 50 participants).

**How can I compare these previous data with our new data? We want to show that our new digital intervention works comparably good as the old one.**

I thought, I could do similar ANOVAs for the 4 older studies separately and compare the effect sizes (partial eta squared). But I could also only compare the intervention groups, doing paired t-tests for each study's intervention group and compare the effect sizes (cohen's d). I was also thinking of pooling all participants together and put them into one model. What would be the best (most correct) way to answer my question?

Thanks in advance, I appreciate it.

Comment: @mdewey's answers is perfect... just an additional hint, simply add study id as additional random effect to your mixed anova model (or a similar mixed effect linear model) and you are done...

Answer (score 2):

If you have the individual data then you can fit a single model to the whole dataset. This is usually called individual participant data meta-analysis if you do it with many different data sources. Sometimes also called one-step IPD to distinguish it from the other option you mention, to analyse each set separately then meta-analyse them, known as two-step meta-analysis.

If you have individual-level covariates then one-step is clearly better otherwise there should be little practical difference.